# App for Mac App Store doesn't run when signed

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode4, code-signing, mac-app-store

I'm new to development for Mac App Store and I'm trying to test my first signed app in development environment (just before get into the mess of receipt validation  !).

I went through the following steps:

1) I created 3 certificates

- a) Mac App
- b) Mac Installer
- c) Development (If I don't create this certificate, I can't create the development provisioning profile at next point 4)

2) I created an App ID

3) I registered my systems

4) I created Development Provisioning Profile

5) I installed the profile on my iMac

6) I loaded the profile into Xcode

7) I set the Code Sign Identity of my project to:  Mac Developer (corresponding to the Development Certificate created at point 1.c)

8) I set the Code Sign Identity of my target to: Mac Developer  (corresponding to the Development Certificate created at point 1.c)

9) I built for running

10) I located the app in finder and clicked on it

11) The icon bounces some times and then the app quits

12) The console shows the following messages

```
Sep 17 10:07:41 Fabrizio-Bocos-iMac taskgated-helper[3186]: Starting taskgated-helper
Sep 17 10:07:42 Fabrizio-Bocos-iMac sandboxd[3187] ([3186]): taskgated-helper(3186) deny file-read-metadata /private/var/db/DetachedSignatures
Sep 17 10:07:42 Fabrizio-Bocos-iMac sandboxd[3187] ([3186]): taskgated-helper(3186) deny file-read-data /private/var/db/DetachedSignatures
Sep 17 10:07:42 Fabrizio-Bocos-iMac sandboxd[3187] ([3186]): taskgated-helper(3186) deny file-read-data /Library/Keychains/System.keychain
Sep 17 10:07:42: --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Sep 17 10:07:42 Fabrizio-Bocos-iMac sandboxd[3187] ([3186]): taskgated-helper(3186) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ocspd
Sep 17 10:07:42: --- last message repeated 3 times ---
Sep 17 10:07:42 Fabrizio-Bocos-iMac sandboxd[3187] ([3186]): taskgated-helper(3186) deny file-read-data /Library/Keychains/System.keychain
Sep 17 10:07:42: --- last message repeated 3 times ---
Sep 17 10:07:42 Fabrizio-Bocos-iMac com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[218] ([0x0-0xe80e8].fabrizio.boco.circuitlab[3183]): Exited: Killed: 9
Sep 17 10:07:42 Fabrizio-Bocos-iMac sandboxd[3187] ([3186]): taskgated-helper(3186) deny file-read-data /Library/Keychains/System.keychain
```

I have googled the messages without a definitive answer.

I have tried the same procedure on a different system (both with Lion 10.7.1 and Xcode 4.1) with the same results

I have deleted and recreated the certificates and the development profile, same result.

Can anyone provide any help ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Updating to 10.7.2 resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but I also have OSX 10.7.2, and XCode 4.2. When I sign the app with the developer profile I created, the app won't launch, though XCode says that it is running the app. Did you by any chance do something else besides updating your OS?

Thanks

Comment: Finally! I managed to solve the issue. So here's the steps for how I found and solved the issue: .Took a look in the Console app what happens when I try to launch. It said: "Killed APP_NAME because of it's use of ubiquity-kvstore identifier entitlement is not allowed". Took a look at the summary on my target and if you have entitlement enabled (needed from now on), xCode automatically puts values to iCloud Containers and key-value-store. I removed these since I don't have iCloud enabled for this app in iTunes Connect.