# codesign gives always no identity found error via terminal

Tags: xcode, terminal, code-signing

I've looked through already existing questions, but none has solved my problems (like recreating certificates). I've built an app where inside the app I have few executables and folders and frameworks. Whenever I try to do `codesign -s "our identity" my.app` always gives no identity found. Can someone give a step by step process of this.

```
codesign -s "Developer ID Application: Sai***** (123123123J)" out/Release/Sai.app
```

Error

> Developer ID Application: Sai****** (123123123J): no identity found,

I tried removing "Developer ID Application" and the serial number, but everything gives the same error

Looking for help in these [lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453511/app-for-mac-app-store-doesnt-run-when-signed)

Comment: Are you manually codesigning the app?  If so, please show the entire `codesign` command line along with any arguments and exact error messages.

Comment: hi,I just updated my question with all the commands

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/38024216/537554

Answer (score 32, accepted):

while I did not do this for apple development code signing, I still think I have some valuable inside that could help you debug such a problem. The difference is that I created my own certificate while you got one from apple.

Check the trust of the cert, it must be trusted for code signing (on yosemite that is the third last in the trust section of the cert view in the keychain access). Be aware that for your code signing the cert should be in the login keychain, I needed it in the System keychain.

At first the cert was not known for codesigning to the keychain, because there was the Extension purpose "Code Signing" missing, you can find this if you look into the keychain and double click on the certificate:

[image]

I fixed that (you can not fix it as Apple provides the cert to you. The extension should just be there):

[image]

Then I added the certificate to the trusted signing certificates, after I had drag&dropped the certificate from the keychain to my desktop, which created the ~/Desktop/gdb-cert.cer (be aware you can omit -d and -r trustRoot:

```
$ sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -p codeSign -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain ~/Desktop/gdb-cert.cer
```

This was a bit tricky because I was mislead by some internet posts and did not look at the man page. Some said you should use add-trust (https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lldb/trunk/docs/code-signing.txt). The terrible bit was that the command succeeded, but did not do what it should.

After that I found the new cert in the trusted certs like so:

```
$ security find-identity -p codesigning

Policy: Code Signing
  Matching identities
      1) E7419032D4..... "Mac Developer: FirstName LastName (K2Q869SWUE)"    (CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED)
      2) ACD43B6... "gdb-cert"
  2 identities found

  Valid identities only
      1) ACD43... "gdb-cert"
  1 valid identities found
```

In my case the apple cert is expired, but the one I was using to sign gdb was not (well, I just created it myself). Also be aware that the policy is named differently for the "security add-trusted-cert"(-p codeSign) and the "security find-identity" command (-p codesigning). I then went on to sign gdb and I also always got:

```
$ codesign --sign gdb-cert.cer --keychain ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain `which gdb`
  gdb-cert.cer: no identity found
```

because I was under the impression that I had to give the file name of the cert file to the --sign option, but that in fact was the CN of the certificate that I should have provided and should be in the trust store. You can find the CN here when double clicking on the cert in the keychain:

[image]

or in the above output of "security find-identity -p codesigning". Then I went on to sign and I had to give it the right keychain. In your case this would have to be the ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain, in my case the System.keychain:

```
 codesign -s gdb-cert --keychain /Library/Keychains/System.keychain `which gdb`
```

That then gave me a working gdb and it should give you a signed application.

Comment: This helped me with codesigning my gdb installation. Thanks!

Comment: i get 'SecTrustSettingsSetTrustSettings: One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid.'

Comment: Any luck with the "one or more param not valid"?

Comment: If you need a self-signed certificate just for testing purposes (as in my case) you can use the Keychain Access tool with the instructions reported here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474751/how-can-i-codesign-an-app-without-being-in-the-mac-developer-program

Comment: I know 2 years passed, but whoever find this, and see "param not valid" thing, try change trustRoot to trustAsRoot

Answer (score 62):

I had some trouble with this as well.   Double-check that your code-signing identity is in your keychain, and you might consider using the SHA-1 fingerprint instead of the name after the -s.

You can find the SHA-1 fingerprint by opening up `Keychain Access` and selecting your `Developer ID Application: FOO` certificate, and then choosing **Get Info**.   From here, scroll to the bottom of the information until you reach **Fingerprints**.   The SHA-1 fingerprint here can be copied and you will have to remove all of the spaces, but after that you will have a 40-character identifier which will be appropriate for placing after the `-s` in your codesign statement.

If you are still having problems locating the key, try the following from Terminal:

```
certtool y | grep Developer\ ID
```

and look for anything with `Developer ID Application` in the `Common Name` to verify that the certificate is actually in a keychain that is accessible from Terminal.  If you don't see anything in response, that would indicate that the keychain containing your credentials is unavailable to your `Terminal` session.   Reasons for this would include things like the keychain being locked, the shell running as another user, executing the command with different permissions (such as `sudo`).

After executing the command above, you should have at a minimum the following:

```
Developer ID Application: <your company name>
Developer ID Installer: <your company name>
Developer ID Certification Authority
```

If you don't have all three, you should go and download the missing elements.   Although you may not currently *need* to build an Installer, there's no harm in having it around.   The Application and Installer elements can be downloaded from the **Mac Certificates** section of the **Certificates, Identifiers, & Profiles** tab on [Apple's Developer site](http://developer.apple.com).  You should have listings there that are not expired.   You may have listings there as well that have expired.  To install the certificates in your keychain:

1. Access the **Apple Developer Site**
2. Access the **Mac Dev Center**
3. Access **Certificates, Identifiers, & Profiles link**
4. Download the Certificates from the portal
5. Double-click on the Certificates and Keychain Access should open
6. Allow Keychain Access to add the Certificates to your Keychain

The *Developer ID Certification Authority* should have been installed by Xcode, but if it wasn't, you can install it yourself.  You will need to download that separately from [Developer ID Authority](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/DeveloperIDCA.cer) or by clicking on the  **+** link in **Certificates** tab and use the link at the bottom to download the Certificate.

This would also be a good time to make sure that you have the *Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority*, which is the basis for some of the signing tools.   It should be installed in your **System** keychain, by the Xcode installer and can be downloaded directly from the **+** link in the **Certificates** tab above or from [Apple WWDR CA](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer).

According to Apple's [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), there are specific keychains that are appropriate for each of the Certificates and keys:

- Your private Keys and your signing certificates (*Developer ID Installer*,*Developer ID Application*, and the App Store Certificates) should be in your **login** keychain
- The *Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority* and *Developer ID Certification Authority* belong in the **System** keychain
- Your developer certificates also belong in your **login** keychain

### Keychain Maintenance

Because Xcode automatically manipulates the keychains, and because some certificates are re-issued regularly when profiles change (although not for Developer ID, since it has multi-year certificates and doesn't require profiles), you can end up with a propagation of unnecessary and potentially confusing certificates in your keychain.   It is a good idea to clean these out when they have expired, as they can create some confusion for Xcode.

**WARNINGS**

- Before performing any maintenance on your Keychains, make sure you have a backup of your keychains
- This process is intended for removing unnecessary Certificates relating to development, If the certificates don't start with *Mac Developer*, *3rd Party Mac Developer*, *iPhone Developer* or *Developer ID*, do not mess with them at this time.   If you accidentally delete the Certificate you received with an email (for example), *even if it has expired*, you may not be able to read the email that you received.

Things to do:

1. Quit Xcode
2. Run Keychain First Aid (from **Keychain Access**) and verify that your keychains are OK
3. Click on the **Certificates** Category on the left sidebar
4. Locate any expired developer certificates of the kinds mentioned above.  They will show up with a small *X* in the lower right corner.
5. Select the Certificates you will be removing and back them up by using **File > Export Items...**
6. Put this file in a safe place and give it a good password
7. Delete the Certificates which you have backed up
8. Look through your remaining certificates and verify that you have the certificates mentioned in the preceding section.  If you don't, you'll need to download, and possibly renew them.
9. Verify that the certificates are in the keychains that are indicated above (all your signing certs should be in your **login** keychain, for example)

Comment: hi, Thanks for the help. I tried the above solution, it gave the same error with sha1 string error before no identity found

Comment: Are you sure you removed just the spaces?   The SHA-1 for the Certificate should be definitive.  If you've double-checked this and it still didn't work, you may need to try running Keychain First Aid from inside of Keychain Access.

Comment: Hi gaige, I tried even keychain repair, it said no problems found

Comment: Do you get any warnings when the software is initially built for Archive by Xcode?

Comment: Oh, I'm not able to open the project in Xcode because the project size of 25GB. Its a dual core cpu with 10GB RAM.

Comment: @SaiKrishna I've added a couple more diagnostics steps to verify that the keychains available in your `Terminal` shell include the certificate you're signing with from the shell, can you check those out?

Comment: Thank you @gaige, I tried them, but they didnt work too. Can you help me of what steps you follow to do a codesign, right from downloading certificates?

Comment: I set up a [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/28550/developer-id-signing) about codesign so that we don't have to do so much back-and-forth in comments.  If you could join, that'd probably be quicker, then we can narrow things down and I can adapt an answer.

Comment: I've added some extensive keychain maintenance and verification information.   Since you are still getting the error indicating it can't find your certificate, we need to focus on that for now.  Your basic `codesign` command looked fine and that command is relatively straightforward.

Comment: Thank You very much gaige. Ill follow the steps  and see how it builds

Comment: @RyanTuck no. Apple issues all the acceptable Developer IDs from their program. However, you don't have to be signed up to sell on the AppStore to use Developer ID.

Comment: @gaige got it - i asked and answered my own question yesterday once i figured it out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474751/how-can-i-codesign-an-app-without-being-in-the-mac-developer-program/27474942#27474942

Comment: Very helpful. As it turns out, in my case the problem was an *extra* developer private key in my login keychain. I (exported and then) removed that key and magically codesign (as spawned by a Crashlytics/Fabric upload) started working again.

Comment: Any idea how to `codesign` via SSH (for unattended builds) and not have to store the `login` keychain password in clear text?

Comment: @dkl Not easy these days. I haven't found a particularly good way to do this that doesn't involve unlocking the keychain, either in an automated fashion or manually unlocking it. You may want to check out some of the mechanisms used by fastlane, which has its own way to store credentials for use by teams in CI environments.

Comment: @gaige a followup: I was able to get signing over SSH to work if I used a non-login keychain.  Yeah, gotta store the password for this keychain, but it only has the signing stuff in it, so not too worried about it.

Answer (score 11):

The Answer finally was very simple. My Private Key was missing. 
For this I revoked the certificate and followed its steps in developer program (Especially creating CSR certificate during the process, which I did not get several times, unless I revoked the certificate).

Comment: Not sure why you revoked my answer.   The absolute first thing that I stated in my answer was "check that your code-signing identity is in your keychain" and I made specific references later to verifying which keychain your private key was in and how to revoke and reinstall it.  But, no matter. Cheers.

Comment: Okay Sorry about that..! Just want users to know exact answer. Not for points sake or meaning that you were answer was wrong..!

Comment: How do I determine if my private key is missing? How is it specified?

Comment: This is a good answer. I purchased a new Mac Mini build machine to replace an old one. The old one had the signing certs. Just importing the signing certs downloaded from Apple didn't work, I also needed the original private key from which the certificate request was formed. So I followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/34063997/28190 to export a new keychain and used that.

Comment: This was my problem too. I had a bit of a fiasco with the keychain between doing the CSR and getting the cert, and my key was lost along the way. I happened to have a backup of the broken keychain, and found the private key in there.

Answer (score 3):

As even

`certtool y | grep "Developer ID Application: xxxx"`

could not display any results, I guessed it was an issue of accessing the desired keychain. So first I verified, the private key could be accessed by any applications in the keychain itself and then I started to use the `k=/Users/myUser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain` option in the certtool command and as this succeeded I did the same with

`codesign --keychain /Users/myUser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain --force --verbose -s "Developer ID Application: xxxx"`

Answer (score 0):

As even

```
certtool y | grep "Developer ID Application: xxxx"
```

could not display any results, I guessed it was an issue of accessing the desired keychain. So first I verified, the private key could be accessed by any applications in the keychain itself and then I started to use the `k=/Users/myUser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain` option in the certtool command and as this succeeded I did the same with

```
codesign --keychain /Users/myUser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain --force --verbose -s "Developer ID Application: xxxx
```