# How can I codesign an app without being in the mac developer program?

Tags: macos

When I try the following:

```
mba:Utilities ryan$ sudo codesign -fs /Applications/Utilities/Boot\ Camp\ Assistant.app/
```

I get this error:

```
/Applications/Utilities/Boot Camp Assistant.app/: no identity found
```

Apparently I don't have a proper code signature, but if I sign up for the mac developer program, it would work.

How can I get a signature without enrolling in the mac developer program?

Comment: Just wondering, what's the goal of code signing for you?  A signature that's not from Apple will not be recognized by Gatekeeper.

Comment: `-s` option requires identity name, like `-`. You missed that. Correct command is: `sudo codesign -fs - /Applications/Utilities/Boot\ Camp\ Assistant.app` (note `-fs - /` part).

Comment: @JWWalker You might need to sign with a self-signed certificate just for testing purposes (e.g. a development build) or if you want to ship your application with your company's channels and sign the binaries with the company certificates instead of the Apple ones.

Comment: `sudo codesign --force --sign - --deep /Applications/x.app`

Answer (score 23):

You need to create a self-signed certificate.

1. Open Keychain Access.
2. Choose Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Create Certificate ...
3. Enter a name
4. Set 'Certificate Type' to 'Code Signing'

Then, your command should look like this, if your certificate name is `my-new-cert`:

```
codesign -fs my-new-cert /Applications/Utilities/Boot\ Camp\ Assistant.app
```

If an error "resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed" appears, you need to remove all extended attributes first, as per Apple [QA1940](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1940/_index.html):

```
xattr -cr /Applications/Utilities/Boot\ Camp\ Assistant.app
```

If an error "/Applications/XYZ.app: code object is not signed at all" appears, it can be mitigated by signing not just the app, but all objects inside it:

```
codesign -fs my-new-cert --deep /Applications/Utilities/Boot\ Camp\ Assistant.app
```

---

This works on OS X 10.10 Yosemite. Update 2023: works on macOS 13.3 Ventura.

Instructions from here: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/keychain-access/kyca8916/mac

Comment: That support link is dead now. Are you sure `sudo` is required?

Comment: `sudo` was causing an issue for me; "error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain." I imagine that's because the key isn't on `root`'s keychain, but rather my own.

Comment: Good answer, so +1 from me. The recent Apple support link is this at the time of writing this: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/keychain-access/kyca8916/mac

Answer (score 2):

If you need to create a self-signed certificate using the **openssl** command line and use it for signing you can do this:

1) Create the **spaghetti.software.extensions** configuration file with the following content:

```
[ ca ] 

default_ca = CA_default 

[ req ] 

distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name 

x509_extensions = v3_ca 

#req_extensions = v3_req 

[req_distinguished_name ] 

CN = spaghetti.software.com 

[ CA_default ] 

x509_extensions = usr_cert 

[ usr_cert ] 

[ v3_ca ] 

basicConstraints = critical, CA:FALSE 

keyUsage = critical, cRLSign, digitalSignature, keyCertSign 

extendedKeyUsage = critical, serverAuth, clientAuth, codeSigning, emailProtection
```

2) Run the following commands to create the certificate and pack both the certificate and the key in a **.p12** file (PKCS12):

```
openssl req -subj '/CN=spaghetti.software.com' -config spaghetti.software.extensions -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout selfSignedKey.pem -out selfSigned.pem -days 365 


openssl pkcs12 -export -out spaghetti.software.p12 -inkey selfSignedKey.pem -in selfSigned.pem
```

3) Create a new **.keychain** file and import the **spaghetti.software.p12** file into the keychain 
(I believe you can do this with the command line as well if you don't want to use the Keychain Access application).

4) Then you can use the certificate to sign:

```
codesign -s "spaghetti.software.com" --force <binaryToSign>
```

You can add `--keychain <MyKeyChain.keychain>` if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't understand why you are trying to resign the Boot Camp Assistant, you can use the codesign tool with a self-signed CA and identity.

Apple has steps to do so in their developer documentation [TN2206: OS X Code Signing In Depth](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG10).

Comment: I need to mess with the Info.plist file for creating a USB boot drive for a windows machine. This requires code signing. Creating a self-signed certificate is definitely the way to go.