# xcodebuild -exportArchive: exportOptionsPlist error for key 'method': expected one of {}

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, xcode7, xcodebuild

I'm using command line xcodebuild tool to export ad-hoc distribution ipa file out of my archive like this:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath /path/Archive.xcarchive -exportPath /path -exportOptionsPlist /path/options.plist
```

However, this command fails with error

```
exportArchive: exportOptionsPlist error for key 'method': expected one of {}, but found ad-hoc
```

No mater what 'method' I provide in my export options plist, it always fails with this error. It also fails if I remove the 'method' option from the plist file.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I suspected xcodebuild tool initially, but it turned out the archive file was invaid. When I opened the archive file in Xcode and tried to export an ipa file manually, I noticed that "Upload to App Store" and "Validate" buttons were disabled. After clicking the "Export" button, it gave me two options: "Save Built Products" and "Export as an Xcode Archive", but there was no Export ad-hoc distribution and the other regular options.

It turned out there were few library files along my .app file in the archive. Xcode considers this a generic archive and not an app archive. Check the Build Phases in your project settings for copying header and library files.

For more details, see [https://developer.apple. com/library/ios/technotes/tn2215/_index.html](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2215/_index.html)

Comment: +1! In my case both a static library and a Common bundle were not "Skipping Install", which caused the issue.

Comment: I forgot that I had a sub-project in my project that was building a library. Removing the public header and setting "skip install" to true for the library in that sub-project's target worked for me.

Comment: I hit this when I had a scheme that was (accidentally) set to build multiple targets.  My CI was set to build this scheme and failed in the export step, I assume because it had > 1 thing in the archive as you describe.  Thanks!

Comment: As it was suggested in post below https://stackoverflow.com/a/49790922/443279. I've open archive and found that there was one of our frameworks that has "skip install" set to NO

Comment: For me the invalid archive was caused by a missing "ApplicationProperties" entry in the Info.plist file inside the .xcarchive. Rebuilding seems to now have created a valid archive. The invalid archive was also apparent by its missing app icon in the Finder (it had a generic archive icon instead).

Comment: Thank you for this answer - it saved my day! I have had same issue (multiply git branches within same project) and Archive from Xcode was showing SUCCESS however Export was showing only 2 options ("Save Built Products" and "Export as an Xcode Archive") plus Fastlane was returning same error. I have changed Target -> Build Settings -> Deployment -> Skip Install to 'No' and it fixed my problem.

Comment: Thanks for this! I too had a framework that was ending up in the xcarchive... setting that framework's "Skip install" to YES for all configs fixed it. Suspect I would never have figured it out without this post.

Comment: @Frederik thank you so much! After I disabled Info.plist generation I was missing a few properties, thanks to you I found what I missing.

Answer (score 10):

In my case one of my static libs did not have `Skip Install` enabled and this resulted in the same problem. When I set in xcode `Skip Install` to `Yes` for that project I fixed that problem.

Comment: Works for me if set `Skip Install` to `No`

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue in one of my projects. After updating Cocoapods from 0.38.2 to 0.39.0 it was gone.

Also, I had a different related issue. Exporting was failing with the following error:

```
2015-10-22 17:16:12.568 xcodebuild[91172:2171408] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/_l/2rl169m16p717gzldvh7n0600000gq/T/MyDriveEU_2015-10-22_17-16-12.568.xcdistributionlogs'.
2015-10-22 17:16:12.860 xcodebuild[91172:2171408] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStep: 0x7fbc13f0c970>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (IDEDistributionErrorDomain error 1.)"
error: exportArchive: The operation couldn’t be completed. (IDEDistributionErrorDomain error 1.)

Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (IDEDistributionErrorDomain error 1.)"

** EXPORT FAILED **
```

It turned out that xcodebuild didn't like `teamID` parameter I added to the `exportOptions.plist`. After I removed it, the app was exported successfully.

Comment: You really saved my day ..Thank you! .. Deleting teamID worked for me

Comment: Check if your Apple WWDR certificate has expired: https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/45siza/this_certificate_has_an_invalid_issuer/

Comment: I never introduced my teamID, still this error is biting my leg :(

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue since two days, 
The issue came from Apple certificates.
Delete Apple Worldwide Developer Relations certification Authority from your keychain (would be expired at 14 Feb) and so renew it by download :

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=02092016a

Comment: If you installed Xcode 7.3 with El Capitan 10.11.4, you will find you have the renewed certificate. You can delete the expired one if you like, though you have no need to delete it.

Answer (score 3):

Old thread but ran into this just today with Xcode 13.3 due to the `.docarchive` being added to the `Products/Applications` folder (both from Xcode and xcodebuild. In Xcode 13.2 and earlier, the documentation archive was not added to this folder so submissions and archive exports worked fine.  As noted in [tech note TN2215](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2215/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011221-CH1-PROJ), there can only be a single product.

[image: Pre-Xcode 13.3]
Xcode 13.2 and earlier

[image: Xcode 13.3]
Xcode 13.3

One workaround is just to turn off the `Build Documentation during 'Build'` setting in Build Settings.  That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2215/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011221-CH1-PROJ

Check the following reasons:

- Your archive contains header files.
- Your archive contains static libraries or frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

Pavel P's solution was

> In my case one of my static libs did not have Skip Install enabled and this resulted in the same problem. When I set in xcode Skip Install to Yes for that project I fixed that problem.

Along the same vein, I was calling "xcodebuild" and passing in SKIP_INSTALL=NO as an option.

e.g.,

```
xcodebuild clean analyze archive -workspace MyWorkspace.xcworkspace -scheme MyScheme -configuration Debug SKIP_INSTALL=NO -archivePath /MyPath/MyArchive.xcarchive
```

Removing SKIP_INSTALL=NO in this case fixed my particular situation.

Comment: This also fixed my problem. The only special thing on my project was a .xcframework for device and simulator, MSAL.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the command was failing because the `method` key was missing or wrong. According to the man page of **xcodebuild** this is the list of allowed methods:

*app-store, validation, ad-hoc, package, enterprise, development, developer-id, and mac-application*

Note that the default value is "*development*". If you don't specify a method or you specify "*developer-id*", then you need to provide also a valid `teamID` key which is reported in the CN of the certificate provided by Apple which is used to sign the application (the teamID is a alphanumeric string at the end of the CN field).

In our case the Apple certificate was only installed in the build machine and no developer could have it installed on the personal computer or VM. So in order to test the package creation and signature we created a self-signed certificate using the steps reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53562496/1423806). Anyway since the teamID was not present in our certificate we had to set the `method` to "*mac-application*". In this case **xcodebuild** was not complaining and the package was generated correctly.

Our plist file was something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>F4keTeamID0</string>
    <key>compileBitcode</key>
    <true/>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>mac-application</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and discovered when looking in KeyChain that the certificate used for signing had been revoked.  Archiving worked fine but when we came to -exportArchive we got this cryptic error. HTH.

Comment: Interesting. Did you manage to get it to work once you introduced a viable certificate into your key-chain? Your answer is actually "don't believe the error message - the problem may be different"

Answer (score -3):

This forum helped me to fix the issue.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/59201#59201

**SOLUTION:** change the key from 'method' to 'export_method' in the exportOptionsPlist.

Comment: I tried it, and it didn't work - it looks like "export_method" isn't at all a supported key in exportOptionsPlist (see xcodebuild -help | grep exportOptionsPlist). I keep receiving the same error for the "method", only now when there's no 'method' key in my .plist, it complains about the default (which is 'development') instead of the real value ('developer-id') I was using. this answer isn't correct.