# xcodebuild -exportArchive command returns error "... 'method': expected one of {}, but found app-store"

Tags: xcode, archive, xcodebuild

We have a static library we've been distributing for some time, and now want to distribute it as a framework.  The static library is built to contain both phone and simulator slices by performing two xcodebuild commands and lipo'ing the results together.  This has been working fine.

But when I initially attempted to apply the same approach to a framework, the App Store validation process griped that the resulting product wasn't built for full bitcode.  Having looked into it, people online are saying I need to use archive instead of build for the device slice.  It results in an xcodebuild command like this:

```
xcodebuild archive -target OurProduct -scheme OurProduct -archivePath ./Archive/OurProduct.xcarchive
```

Now at this point I appear to have a valid xcarchive.  Then I'm running:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath "./Archive/OurProduct.xcarchive" -exportPath "./Archive/OurProduct.framework" -exportOptionsPlist "./exportOptions.plist"
```

But I get the error:

> error: exportArchive: exportOptionsPlist error for key 'method':
>   expected one of {}, but found app-store

"app-store" is the value of key "method" in my export options plist file.  I need some help trying to understand what could be the problem here, or if there's a more proper way to do this.

Comment: Hi John, any luck with this?

Comment: @UriKlar yeah, I spoke with Apple and they provided a solution in the form of, believe it or not, a PDF, with a confidentiality notice at the top.  It does work, but I'm prohibited from disclosing any portion of it.  I can only suggest you speak with Apple as part of a TSI.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841300/xcodebuild-exportarchive-exportoptionsplist-error-for-key-method-expected-o

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xcodebuild -exportArchive: exportOptionsPlist error for key 'method': expected one of {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841300/xcodebuild-exportarchive-exportoptionsplist-error-for-key-method-expected-o)

Answer (score 0):

setting `skip_install` to `YES` fixed my issue.