# Why is my app really slow to start when I authorized it to control my system?

Tags: macos, accessibility

I developed a 32-bit application and I want to check if it is compatible with Mojave. According to [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/109283), I have to authorize my application to control my system in the Accessibility settings in order to use some functionality, which I did.

After I changed this setting, my app now takes around 5 minutes to start. Why? How can I reduce the lauching time without changing the Accessibility settings?

---

**EDIT:** I reproduce the problem with a 64-bits application on ElCapitain and Sierra (and I believe it also happens in High Sierra). Here is the procedure to reproduce it.

Create a C++ file like this one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

#define SIZE 1000000000
char dummy[SIZE] = {'a'};

int main()
{
    if(AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(NULL))
        std::cout << "Trusted" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Not trusted" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I create a `dummy` variable in order to increase the size of the binary. I noticed the problem is more notable with large application. Also `AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions` returns `true` if the application is authorized to control the system.

Compile it:
`clang++ -framework ApplicationServices repro.cpp -o repro`

Create a bundle application and put `repro` in MacOS directory:

```
repro.app
 |_ Contents
     |_ MacOS
         |_ repro
```

Execute it for the first time:

```
$ date && open repro.app && date
Ven 10 mai 2019 16:58:10 CEST
Ven 10 mai 2019 16:58:10 CEST
```

As we can see, it takes less than a second to execute the application.

Now, add `repro.app` in the list of trusted applications: System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy tab -> Accessibility -> Add `repro.app` in the list.

Run the app a second time:

```
$ date && open repro.app && date
Ven 10 mai 2019 17:06:31 CEST
Ven 10 mai 2019 17:06:36 CEST
```

This time, it takes more than 5 seconds to execute it.

It's relatively fast for this sample binary but the application I work on takes multiple minutes to start. Where is the issue?

Comment: A more information would be helpful.  Did it run Ok in High Sierra?

Comment: @historystamp Yes. All is OK with previous version of Mac OS. But when I checked if my app is compatible with Mojave, I detected a first problem (CoreGraphics Event didn't work anymore), I corrected by changing the Accessibility settings.

Comment: This happens with apps that are only *ad hoc* code-signed. If you code-sign them properly, it shouldn't happen. Once you do that, you may need to remove your app from the permissions list in System Preferences and let it be re-added on next use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by @KenThomases in comments, I have to sign my application. To do that, I created a [self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27474942/7334162).

Then, I just have to use `codesign` to sign my app:

```
$ codesign --deep -s MyIdentity repro.app
```

In my toy example, the `--deep` option is not useful but I have to use it to sign all the dependancies of the application I work on.

To finish, I have to deactivate/reactivate the permissions of my application in the System Preferences. If I run it:

```
$ date && open repro.app && date
Lun 13 mai 2019 17:27:32 CEST
Lun 13 mai 2019 17:27:32 CEST
```